# Twisted pythonLoggingObservers raise maximum recursion error?

Tags: python, twisted

In python 2.7.5, there is a bug in logging.handlers https://bugs.python.org/issue18940

Twisted version is 17.5.0, when meeting the python logging bug, the twisted code will raise the RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Logging handler is TimedRotatingFileHandler, when doing the rorate and the log file is deleted by crontab at that time and then the twisted will maximum recursion depth exceeded.

In twisted, pythonLoggingObservers is used, and Im sure the observer caused the bug by strace the process. I read the twised code but can't find the reason, I want to know how this bug is happen?

the strace output: https://gist.github.com/5f713d00285195e8dd949def5d7d1aa2

The default code is complex, extract the code logic is like this:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from twisted.web import server,resource
from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.python.log import PythonLoggingObserver
from twisted.internet import reactor


class SiteWithoutLogging(server.Site):
    def startFactory(self):
        server.Site.startFactory(self)
        del self.logFile

class HelpPage(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>help</body></html>"

class ServiceCreatorMixIn(object):
    def create_service(self, name, service_class, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Creata a generic service.'''
        s = service_class(*args, **kwargs)
        s.setName(name)
        return s

    def create_tcp_server(self, name, factory):
        '''Create a TCP server.'''
        port = 8080
        return self.create_service(name, internet.TCPServer, port, factory, interface="0.0.0.0")

    def create_rpc_server_without_logging(self, name):
        '''Create a RPC server.'''
        res = resource.Resource()
        res.putChild("/", HelpPage())
        site = SiteWithoutLogging(res)
        return self.create_tcp_server(name, site)


class MyLoggingObserver(PythonLoggingObserver):
    def __init__(self, loggerName="twisted"):
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(message)s")
        handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("./app.log", 'S')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        PythonLoggingObserver.__init__(self, loggerName)

    class App(ServiceCreatorMixIn):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self._initlog()
            self._initapp()

        def _initlog(self):
            observer = MyLoggingObserver(self.name)
            observer.start()

        def _initapp(self):
            self.app = service.Application(self.name)
            self.multiService = service.MultiService()
            self.multiService.setServiceParent(self.app)
            reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(129)

app = App('app')
app.create_rpc_server_without_logging('app').setServiceParent(app.multiService)
application = app.app
```

to replay the maximum recursion just run `twistd -y test.py -r epoll`, it will make the rorate per second, and then add a crontab to delete
the app.log, wait a minute, the cpu will 100% load, and there are many
twistd.log, in the log file, the content is the exceptions.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

the error info:

```
2017-11-28T20:37:12+0800 [-]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 346, in doRollover
2017-11-28T20:37:12+0800 [twisted.logger._observer#critical] Temporarily disabling observer LegacyLogObserverWrapper(<bound method MyLoggingObserver.emit of <MyLoggingObserver object at 0x1dfac50>>) due to exception: [Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py:67:print_tb
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py:13:_print
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_io.py:170:write
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:132:emit
    --- <exception caught here> ---
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:131:__call__
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:93:__call__
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py:595:emit
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py:154:publishToNewObserver
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py:116:__call__
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1213:log
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1268:_log
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1278:handle
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1318:callHandlers
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:749:handle
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py:82:emit
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:802:handleError
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py:124:print_exception
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py:13:_print
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_io.py:170:write
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:132:emit
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:136:__call__
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:156:_errorLoggerForObserver
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py:81:__init__
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:52:__init__
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py:32:_namespaceFromCallingContext
    /tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/compat.py:110:currentframe
    ]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py", line 67, in print_tb
        '  File "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name))
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py", line 13, in _print
        file.write(str+terminator)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_io.py", line 170, in write
        self.log.emit(self.level, format=u"{log_io}", log_io=line)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 132, in emit
        self.observer(event)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py", line 131, in __call__
        observer(event)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py", line 93, in __call__
        self.legacyObserver(event)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 595, in emit
        _publishNew(self._newObserver, eventDict, textFromEventDict)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_legacy.py", line 154, in publishToNewObserver
        observer(eventDict)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_stdlib.py", line 116, in __call__
        stdlibLevel, StringifiableFromEvent(event), exc_info=excInfo)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1213, in log
        self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1268, in _log
        self.handle(record)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1278, in handle
        self.callHandlers(record)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1318, in callHandlers
        hdlr.handle(record)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 749, in handle
        self.emit(record)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 82, in emit
        self.handleError(record)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 802, in handleError
        None, sys.stderr)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
        _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py", line 13, in _print
        file.write(str+terminator)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_io.py", line 170, in write
        self.log.emit(self.level, format=u"{log_io}", log_io=line)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 132, in emit
        self.observer(event)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py", line 136, in __call__
        errorLogger = self._errorLoggerForObserver(brokenObserver)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py", line 156, in _errorLoggerForObserver
        if obs is not observer
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_observer.py", line 81, in __init__
        self.log = Logger(observer=self)
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 52, in __init__
        namespace = self._namespaceFromCallingContext()
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/logger/_logger.py", line 32, in _namespaceFromCallingContext
        return currentframe(2).f_globals["__name__"]
    File "/tmp/test_twisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", line 110, in currentframe
        for x in range(n + 1):
    exceptions.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Try adding a http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hi @Jean-PaulCalderone, I'm sorry to can't describe the question clearly, I add a demo code and error info